# $x_n$ doesn't converge to zero and is always smaller than zero and a properly divergent sequence $y_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

There's a sequence $y_n\rightarrow\infty$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$.
Proof that if $x_n$ doesn't converge to zero and for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ : $x_n<0$
then there's a subsequence $x_{n_j}$ of $x_n$ such that $x_{n_j}y_{n_j}\rightarrow-\infty$ for $j\rightarrow\infty$.

I have no clue how to proof this. The subsequence thing confuses me so much. If all values of $x_n$ are smaller than zero and are multiplied with $y_n$ shouldn't it automatically converge to $-\infty$?

Thanks for your help in advance!!

Comment: What if $y_n=n$ and $x_n=-\frac1n$. All values of $x_n$ are smaller than $0$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_ny_n)=-1$.

Comment: Take $ y_n = n $ and $ x_{2n} = -\frac{1}{2n} $ and $ x_{2n+1} = -1 $ (you are not told that $ x_n $ is convergent).

Comment: @shortmanikos Note that $x_{2n+1}y_{2n+1} = -2n-1$ which converges to $-\infty$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring In my example $ x_n $ is not convergent (it has a subsequence that goes to $-1$). I did not claim that I gave a counterexample. I tried to explain why it is necessary to consider a subsequence, by giving an example where $ x_n y_n $ does not converge to $ - \infty $.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Sure. My example was due to the sentence “If all values of $x_n$ are smaller than zero and are multiplied with $y_n$ shouldn't it automatically converge to $-\infty$?
”

Comment: Fair enough.  I just misinterpreted your intentions.

Answer (score 2):

Since $(x_n)_n$ doesn't converge to zero, there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ and a subsequence $(x_{n_j})_j$ such that $|x_{n_j}| \ge \varepsilon$ for all $j \in \Bbb{N}$.

Since $x_{n_j} < 0$, it has to be $x_{n_j} \le -\varepsilon$. For large enough $j$ we have $y_{n_j} \ge 0$ so $$x_{n_j}y_{n_j} \le -\varepsilon y_{n_j} \xrightarrow{j\to\infty} -\infty.$$

Comment: Strictly speaking, you sues $y_n\ge0$, which holds "only" for almost all $n$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks, good point.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $y_n=n, x_n=-\frac1n$. We easily see that $x_ny_n$ doesn't automatically diverge to $-\infty$ just because $x_n$ are negative. This is the reason we can't have $x_n\to0$.

Next, consider $y_n=n$ and
$$
x_n=\cases{\frac1n& if $n$ is even\\-1& otherwise}
$$
Take a look at the sequence $x_ny_n$ to see why we need to work with a subsequence.

As for the proof itself, consider this: the fact that $x_n$ does not converge to $0$ (in conjunction with $x_n<0$) means

> There is an $\varepsilon < 0$ such that there are infinitely many terms that fulfill $x_n<\varepsilon$

Can you guess, just from reading the above paragraph (and the fact that this is the hint I give) what a suitable subsequence might be?

Comment: In the case of the $x_n$ you gave, it should be $x_{2k-1}$ because then $x_{2k-1}y_{2k-1}=-y_{2k-1}$ which goes to negative infinity?

Comment: @educationalwin That's one subsequence that works. It's probably the easiest one. There are other choices too, but they ultimately boil down to basically the same thing. With my last paragraph, I did mean what a suitable subsequence might be in the more general case, though.

Comment: one that negates the term of $y_{n_j}$? else it can't diverge properly to negative infinity or am I missing something out? probably missunderstood what you mean by "in a more general case"

Comment: or a subsequence of $x_n$ that properly diverges to negative infinity itself? That would statisfy the condition that there are infinitely many terms that fulfill $x_n<\epsilon$

Comment: @educationalwin We do not know that there is a subsequence of $x_n$ that diverges to $-\infty$ (consider my second example $x_n$). Look at the second to last paragraph (the highlighted one). Forget the original problem for a second, and read the paragraph thoroughly. Does it, by itself, hint towards a particular subsequence?

Comment: not really? could be any subsequence of $x_n$ because $x_n$ is always smaller than zero?

Comment: Did you read and work through my second example and see what happens if you pick the "entire sequence" subsequence? So you _can't_ pick any subsequence. Here is another hint: a subsequence can also be thought of as an infinite collection of terms.